# Merging two datasets with only one duplicate column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to merge two datasets like so

```
V1
 Berry
```

as the first data set and

```
V4   V6    V7   V1
Temp Temp  Temp Temp
```

To make

```
V4   V6    V7   V1
Temp Temp  Temp Temp
NA   NA    NA    Berry
```

I have tried using

```
test2<-merge(Session1t, temp2, by=temp1, all = TRUE)
```

Where temp1 is the column name V1 stored as a value. The problem I am having is I cannot explicitly state by="V1", because this is inside of a loop where the column names change for each iteration and I am unsure of how to merge the two datasets effectively. The closest I have gotten was merging them where it would create two V1 columns, but that is obviously not something that I can use.

Comment: What if you drop the `by=temp1`? If they have same variable names, it will merge them... `merge(Session1t, temp2, all = T)` works for me, else post some data to make your problem reproducible. You might also want to read [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: If I do that I get an undefined columns selected error. The first data set is only the one column, nothing else. I will look into making it more reproducible, but that might take me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `bind_rows` function from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package.

```
# Create example data frame D1
D1 <- read.table(text = "V1
 Berry",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Create example data frame D2
D2 <- read.table(text = "V4   V6    V7   V1
                 Temp Temp  Temp Temp",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load package
library(dplyr)

# Combine two data frames
D3 <- bind_rows(D2, D1)

D3
#     V4   V6   V7    V1
# 1 Temp Temp Temp  Temp
# 2 <NA> <NA> <NA> Berry
```

We can also use the `rbind` function from base R, which is similar to `bind_rows`, but we need to create columns not in `D1`or `D2` with `NA` first.

```
# Get columns not match
NACol <- setdiff(names(D2), names(D1))

# Create columns based on NACol with NA
for (i in NACol){
  D1[[i]] <- NA
}

# Combine tow data frames
D3 <- rbind(D2, D1)
D3
#     V4   V6   V7    V1
# 1 Temp Temp Temp  Temp
# 2 <NA> <NA> <NA> Berry
```